# Javascript rounding v c# rounding

Tags: c#, javascript

I have an invoice page in ASP.NET MVC.

I am calculating GST.

In javascript this  the result.

```
165.45 * 0.1 = 16.544999999999998
```

In C# I get

```
165.45 * 0.1 = 16.545
```

These round differently

I want to round both to 2 decimal places but they give different answers

Javascript = 16.54

C# = 16.55  Which is what I want.

Any ideas how to get them the same??

Comment: postback the C# calculated value?

Answer (score 3):

In C# if you're using `double`, you're *not* really getting 16.55 - it may print out to that, but that's not the real value. In both cases you should be using a decimal-based type instead of a binary-based type. In C# that's easy - you can use the `decimal` (aka `System.Decimal`) type. I don't know if there's an equivalent in JavaScript, unfortunately.

You should probably read up on [binary floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) and [decimal floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Decimal.aspx) to understand why this is important. (Those are .NET-focused articles, but the principles apply to JS too.)

For currency values, one way to avoid this being a problem is to use integers to start with - keep the number of pennies (cents, whatever) in your value, and then display it by just writing out `(number / 100) + "." + (number % 100)` (using a different decimal separator if necessary). I strongly suspect you'll find this the best way to get consistent and predictable results for this particular situation.

Comment: There is no `decimal` equivalent in JavaScript. All JavaScript numbers are IEEE-754 doubles behind-the-scenes.

Comment: @LukeH: Are there any third-party libraries providing something like Java's BigDecimal?

Comment: There's BigDecimal for JavaScript, which I think is an attempt at a direct port of the Java version. I have no idea whether it's any good or not. http://freshmeat.net/projects/js_bigdecimal

Comment: @LukeH: Thanks. I suspect that the "use integers and division/modulus by 100" is the simplest answer in this case.

Comment: Definitely. That's what I resort to on the rare occasions when I do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there might not be a consistent way to round numbers in Javascript, since browsers use different JS engines that behave differently.

That said, you should do mission-critical calculations on the server side.
*Never, ever* trust client input.